# Installing Impala on Amazon EMR 4.1 and Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-cdh, amazon-emr, impala

I want to know that can we install Impala 2.1 on Amazon EMR 4.1 / 4.2 or on Amazon EC2 ?? Please suggest any way to setup Impala 2.1 on Amazon EMR or EC2 ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the GUI for creating EMR-clusters don't include the Impala option.

Fortunately, this [here](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/impala) link on github describes the CLI commands/bootstrap actions to get a cluster with Impala 2.2. Have not tried it myself yet, though.

For reference, here is a [list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html) to the AMI:s available, so you can see what else you get installed when bootstrapping the image. (seems that the AMI only covers Impala 1.2.4, but the bootstrap action seems to install 2.2)